# R Shiny renderDT is returning a blank table

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating another shiny app that allows the user to upload a `CSV` file and then display the data as table. The app works just fine however the table is blank even though it is picking up the column names.

How can I fix this?

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(Reference.Number = c("33333", "44444", "22222", 
"55555", "66666"), Request.Date = c("1/6/2022", "1/6/2022", "1/19/2022", 
"1/20/2021", "1/24/2022"), Requestor.Name = c("Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", 
"Comm Dist 3 by Kitty", "Updated maps for David", 
"    Stone Cold", "Updated SOE 60 inch wall map"), Requestor.Dept.Div = c("C 3 Staff", 
"C 3 Staff", "Unincorp & Comm", "Mt.Rushmore AME Church Ft. Billy", 
"SOE"), Requestor.Phone = c("", "", "", "", ""), Contact.Person = c("Tommy", 
"Tommy", "Bob", "Bob", "Joe"), Contact.Phone = c("1111", 
"2222", "3333", "ext 1111", "3434"), Deadline = c("1/20/2022", 
"1/20/2022", "1/22/2022", "", "1/24/2022"), Project.Description = c("45x36 portrait map ", 
"45x36 portrait map  ", 
"24x24 Unincorporated areas, "Percent Females Aged 25 - 55  Below Poverty Level By Zip Code", 
"SOE Wall Map 60x60 p), Project.File.Location = c("", 
"", "C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14785 Unincorporated 24x24.pdf", 
"C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel.aprx", 
"C:\\ABC\\Tommy\\work|Map-Projects\\BD Unincororated\\#14786 V P 60x60.pdf"
), PDF.File.....Map.Name.... = c("", "", "", "C:\\ABC\\Demographics\\Demographic_Request\\FemalesAge10-18BelowPoveryLevel\\pdfs\\MapNo14785.pdf", 
""), Assigned.To = c("", "", "", "", ""), Completion.Date = c("", 
"", "", "", ""), Notes = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Year = c(2022, 
2022, 2022, 2022, 2022)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Current Output:

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui =   navbarPage(title = div("Table"),
                  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                  tabPanel("Projects",
                           icon = icon("info"),
                           div(p(h1("Instructions:"),style="text-align: justify;")),
                           p("1. The user can upload a CSV file.", style="color:white"),
                           p("2. Based on the uploaded file, the app will return an interactive table that is searchable.", style="color:white"),
                           p("3. Based on the uploaded file, the app will allow the user to add their project details in new rows or delete existing ones.", style="color:white"),
                           uiOutput("all"),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      radioButtons(
                        "File_Type",
                        label = "Choose File type",
                        choices = list(".csv/txt" = 1, ".xlsx" = 2),
                        selected = 1,
                        inline = TRUE
                      ),
                      
                      fileInput('file2', 'Upload Your Data',
                                accept = c(
                                  'text/csv',
                                  'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain',
                                  '.csv',
                                  '.xlsx'
                                ))),
                    mainPanel(
                      downloadButton("download1","Download data as csv"),                
                      DTOutput("contents")),)
                    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  myData = reactive({
    req(input$file2)
    inFile = input$file2
    if (is.null(inFile)) return(NULL)
    data = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
    data
  })
  
  output$contents = renderDT({
    
    req(myData())
    myData()  
    
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The DT table isn't blank. It's just that the font color set by your theme choice is `"white"` which makes the content nearly invisible. You could check by selecting a row of your table or uncommenting the line where your set the theme or having a closer look at the your image.

Comment: @stefan `p(.... style = "color:white")` is causing the issue?

Comment: Nop. `theme = shinytheme("cyborg")`. To me it looks like while the font color for the table gets inverted by the theme, the background fill color is not.

Comment: If so then how can I keep the text in the three `p`s, the `Search Bar text` (text entered in the search bar), the word `Search` and the table `page numbers` `white` since my background image is sort of `black`? The table font color will stay `black`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of your theme is not optimized with dataTable.

Add this to your UI

```r
tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th {color: white}")
```

like this

```r
...

ui =   navbarPage(title = div("Table"),
                  theme = shinytheme("cyborg"),
                  tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th {color: white}"),
                  tabPanel("Projects",

...
```

Comment: how can I keep the `Search Bar text `(text entered in the search bar), the word `Search` and the `table page numbers` `white` since my background image is sort of `black`? The table font color will stay `black` though since table background is white.

Comment: Should I post another question for this commemt?

Comment: @Mandalorian Use this `tags$style("table, .table {color: unset;} .dataTable th, .datatables input {color: white}")`